# Visual Studio cannot find custom tool RazorGenerator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, nuget, razorgenerator

I've installed the [NuGet package](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) for `RazorGenerator.mvc` and then run the shell command `Enable-RazorGenerator` and get the following message:

> Exception calling "RunCustomTool" with "0" argument(s): "The custom tool 'RazorGenerator' failed.  The method or operation is not implemented."At \packages\RazorGenerator.Mvc.1.3.2.0\tools\RazorGenerator.psm1:77 char:40+                 $_.Object.RunCustomTool <<<< ()    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

I also tried right-clicking and selecting "Run Custom Tool" and it provides a dialog stating it cannot find the custom tool `RazorGenerator` on the system.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I had that same problem too and I realized that along with the package for the solution you will also need to install the Visual Studio Extension called **RazorGenerator**

- Go to **Tools**, then **Extension Manager**
- Search for **Razor Generator**
- Click the **Download** button.
- Once the install has completed, **restart** Visual Studio.

Comment: This worked - I didn't know you need to have the **RazorGenerator** extension too - not just the nuget **RazorGenerator.mvc** package.

Comment: Yea, I didn't realize it either the documentation didn't really point it out very well... Glad it worked for you.

Comment: [Here is a custom Razor Generator installer for VS2013 Preview](http://msdnsub.blob.core.windows.net/public/RazorGenerator2013.vsix) to enable Razor Generator as [Razor Generator is not yet in the VS 2013 Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1f6ec6ff-e89b-4c47-8e79-d2d68df894ec).

Comment: Why are both the Extension and the NuGet package necessary?

Comment: I just installed Visual Studio 15 preview 4 but RazorGenerator does not seem to be available

Comment: Need to install the Extension and the nuget package

Comment: @Gabe Maybe worth clarifying that the extension is "Razor Generator" (with the space) - you've written it both ways in the answer above. The extensions search function returns no results for "RazorGenerator" which isn't terribly helpful of it.

Comment: @Jon well considering this was written 6 years ago it used to be called "RazorGenerator." I'm sorry if my help wasn't helpful enough for you. Based on the feedback it was for many others. I don't have time to update everyone of my answers.

Comment: @Gabe I'm sorry you're so busy. My thinking was: your helpful answer still exists; I found it and others found it (note the other comments from 2013, 2015, 2016, 2017); it could be more helpful. Please excuse me for trying to make the world a better place, says one PA commenter to another.

Comment: I had the same problem. It worked for me in Visual Studio 2013. Thx.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, you can find and install the Razor Generator extension from Tools -> Extensions and Updates.

Comment: Just for an update, in Visual Studio 2019 there is an independent tab just for Extensions.
So it should be:
Extensions>Manage Extensions